# Performance testing tools for testing rest api's

Tags: rest, ssl, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a (asp.net)web service service and I am using Apigee as API management tool. I wanted to know some performance testing tools to test my api's and also wanted to evaluate them based on SSL support, encryption, can be automated, integration with source control(tfs) 
Can anybody suggest some tool options or any other information regarding performance testing rest api?

Comment: Let's refer this article "top 10 API testing tools", hope this help https://medium.com/@alicealdaine/top-10-api-testing-tools-rest-soap-services-5395cb03cfa9

Answer (score 5):

Basically any performance testing tool which supports HTTP(S) protocol and setting headers can be used for load testing APIs.

The most popular tool for web services testing is [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html). It can be used for load testing as well.

Other free and open source tools are:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide for detailed description of the above softwares, sample test reports and comparison matrix.

Personally I would go for JMeter as SoapUI and Gatling do not scale (i.e. if one machine won't be able to produce the anticipated load it will be your bottleneck), Grinder and Tsung are not that user-friendly (Python and XML test definition formats correspondingly)

Answer (score 0):

[Restbird](https://restbird.org), offer docker deployment and support javascript, python and Golang to add logic, everything is stored in local file system makes it easy to scale .